# How to generate all possible datasets different by at most one row from an initial dataset?

Tags: apache-spark

Given a dataset `initDs` i want to generate all possible datasets having one row of difference with the initial dataset `initDs`. The problem is about generating all possible datasets having at most one row difference with `initDs`. To better explain the generated datasets (list of `genDs`) should comply with the following constraint (for all generated `genDs`) :

```
if (initDataset.except(genDs).count() == 1)
   do something
```

My question is how to generate the dataset combinations ?

Comment: can you give some examples of what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this :)

```scala
import sparkSession.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq("A", "B", "C", "D")
  .toDF("letter")
  .withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id)

val ids = 0L to (df.count() - 1)
val genDfs = ids.map(excludedId => df.where( col("id") =!= lit(excludedId) ).drop("id"))

genDfs.foreach(_.show)
```

**Output**

```scala
+------+
|letter|
+------+
|     B|
|     C|
|     D|
+------+

+------+
|letter|
+------+
|     A|
|     C|
|     D|
+------+

+------+
|letter|
+------+
|     A|
|     B|
|     D|
+------+

+------+
|letter|
+------+
|     A|
|     B|
|     C|
+------+
```

Comment: Exactly what i wanted, but i need it in JAVA please, thanks !